# Use before_filter define in main_app inside engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I have a before filter that I currently use inside my main_app call "action" and I normally call it by saying

```
before_filter :action
```

Right now I have an engine that I need to use that same filter, but if I use that exact method I get the following error:

```
undefined method `action' (for Engine bla bla..)
```

For other cases I just added main_app upfront and that solved the issue. Not the case. Any help?

*UPDATE*
Right now i have this:

```
module MyEngine
  class MyEngineController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :main_app do
      :action
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do something like

```
class MyController < EngineController
    skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:setup]

    def setup
        super
    end
end
```

Comment: worked. thanks for the helped. prevented me from hours of frustration

Comment: @MZaragoza, I am stuck at a very similar situation, could you please elaborate what this solution does?

Comment: @nkm if you want to write your question I would gladly take a stab at it, just pm me with your question url

Comment: Doing the tests just realized it didn;t worked as expected. My engine controller is a ApplicationControoller, not an EngineController. Please see my update